# rosmake vs. make

Tags: rosmake, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the difference between *make* and *rosmake*? Which one is recommended?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10614/rosmake-vs.-make/) by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) on ROS Answers with karma: 347 on 2011-07-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running `rosmake` is a superset of `make`. In particular, `rosmake` runs `make` on all of a package's dependencies (as defined in `manifest.xml`), including recursive dependencies. By contrast, `make` just builds the current package.

You should run `rosmake` the first time you build a package (say, when you first install it), when you change a package's `manifest.xml` (in case you need to recursively build a newly-added dependency), or when a package's dependency needs to be rebuilt.

My workflow goes like this:

1. Sit down at my desk in the morning.
2. `rosinstall ~/ros /opt/ros/diamondback` (this gets all of my source packages up-to-date)
3. `rosmake foo` (where `foo` is the package I'm currently developing; this makes sure the dependencies and everything else are properly dealt with)
4. After that, while working on `foo`, just use `make`.

A note: the packages that are distributed as binaries (the `.deb` files) include a `ROS_NOBUILD` file that causes `rosmake` to skip right over them; this causes them to (appear to) build very fast.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-10-02**:
NB: these days, it's "rosinstall ~/ros /opt/ros/electric". The appropriate letter of the alphabet will evolve over time...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that *rosmake* attempts to compile all the package's dependencies, whereas *make* only compiles the package, so it's faster.

---

Originally posted by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) with karma: 347 on 2011-07-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*make* does finish first because it only compiles the current package that you are working on. It only works if you are in the root directory of that package.

*rosmake* compiles the package (or stack) named (e.g. `rosmake my_package`) or if you are working in a package's root directory and don't name a package, the current package. *rosmake* also checks and compiles any dependencies if required.

My rule of thumb is to *rosmake* the first time and anytime I change the manifest or CMakeLists.txt as well as anytime I modify any of a packages dependencies. If I have only made changes to source code in the package itself, I just use *make*.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-07-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3